# Refer to QueryTable objects by name

Tags: excel, vba

I am developing a MS Excel 2013 tool with VBA, which involves the use of QueryTables.

One inconvenience is accessing **existing** QueryTables within an Excel worksheet. Currently, the only method I can find to access a query table is by integer indexing. I came up with the following code for a quick proof of concept:

```
Sub RefreshDataQuery()

Dim querySheet As Worksheet
Dim interface As Worksheet

Set querySheet = Worksheets("QTable")
Set interface = Worksheets("Interface")

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim QT As QueryTable

Dim startTime As Double
Dim endTime As Double

Set QT = querySheet.ListObjects.item(1).QueryTable

startTime = Timer
QT.Refresh
endTime = Timer - startTime

interface.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Elapsed time to run query"
interface.Cells(1, 2).Value = endTime
interface.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Seconds"

End Sub
```

This works, but I don't want to do it this way. The end product tool will have up to five different QueryTables. I want to refer to a QueryTable by its name.

How could I translate:

```
Set QT = querySheet.ListObjects.item(1).QueryTable
```

To something along the lines of:

```
Set QT = querySheet.ListObjects.items.QueryTable("My Query Table")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this MSDN link for ListObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff841237%28v=office.14%29.aspx) there isn't any collection of `QueryTables` being a property of `ListObjects`. Correct code is:

```
Set QT = querySheet.ListObjects.items(1).QueryTable
```

What you possibly need is to refer to appropriate `ListObject item` like (just example code):

```
Dim LS as ListObject
Set LS = querySheet.ListObjects("My LO 1")
Set QT = LS.QueryTable
```

The other alternative is to refer to QT through `WorkSheet property` in this way:

```
Set QT = Worksheet("QTable").QueryTables("My Query Table")
```

Comment: Set QT = querySheet.ListObjects.items.QueryTable doesn't compile. I don't see an items propery for ListObjects. For your second suggestion, Set QT = Worksheet("QTable").QueryTables("My Query Table"), this doesn't work for me as the QTable was pre-existing.

Comment: I changed that to: `Set QT = querySheet.ListObjects.items(1).QueryTable` which is similar to your code.

Comment: what do you mean that 'worksheet was pre-existing?'... which is obvious- change the name of QT to one which you really have. You can always check number of QT in sheet in this way: `Debug.Print Worksheets("QTable").QueryTables.Count` and the name of each of the QT in this way: `ly have. You can always check number of QT in sheet in this way: `Debug.Print Worksheets("QTable").QueryTables(1).Name` for first one.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. The QueryTable was built not through VBA. It was built by various users through Data Connections Wizard. The count for the code you posted, which I attempted earlier, will display 0 even though I can access the QueryTable through ListObjects.item(1).QueryTable

Comment: So, I guess ListObject data are from external source. Therefore, to get to QT you need to find appropriate ListObject and use `ListObject.QueryTable` reference.

Answer (score 10):

In Excel 2003 and prior, an external data connection would create a QueryTable object whose parent was a worksheet. You could access the QueryTable object, for one, through the QueryTables collection object. Like most collection objects, you can pass an index number or a name to the (default) Item method to get it.

```
Sheet1.QueryTables("MyQtName")
```

When you open a 2003 worksheet in a new version, it still has a QueryTable object and can be accessed the same way. Even if you convert the file format, the QueryTable persists.

In 2007 and later versions, there are only three ways to create a QueryTable that will be a member of Worksheet.QueryTables:

1. Through code
2. Data - From Text
3. Data - From Web

All other UI external data connections in these new versions will result not in a QueryTables member, but in a ListObject. That ListObject will have one and only one QueryTable object that can be accessed via the ListObject.QueryTable property.

Here's the bad news. The QueryTable whose parent in a ListObject doesn't have a Name property. Well, it's there, but you will get a runtime error 1004 if you try to access it. I guess MS decided since there's only one QueryTable per ListObject, it didn't make sense that it should have a name.

If you try to convert a Worksheet.QueryTables.QueryTable into a ListObject, the external data connection goes away and the new ListObject doesn't have a QueryTable.

Since your QueryTables.Count is returning zero, all of your QueryTables are inside ListObjects and don't have names. The ListObjects have names. You can use

```
Sheet1.ListObjects("MyListName").QueryTable
```

Here's a function that takes a name and a worksheet and returns a QueryTable that either has that name or is a child of a ListObject that has that name.

```
Public Function QueryTableByName(ByVal sName As String, ByRef sh As Worksheet) As QueryTable

    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim lo As ListObject

    On Error Resume Next
        Set qt = sh.QueryTables(sName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If qt Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
            Set lo = sh.ListObjects(sName)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not lo Is Nothing Then
            On Error Resume Next
                Set qt = lo.QueryTable
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End If

    Set QueryTableByName = qt

End Function
```

Comment: Great summary and function!

Comment: This was very helpful and descriptive. Thanks!

Comment: @Dick Kusleika Sadly it appears ListObjects no longer has a name property in 2013 or a QueryTable property.

Comment: ListObjects is a collection object that holds all of the ListObject objects on a worksheet. ListObject is an object that holds a single instance. The collection object never had a Name or QueryTable property, but ListObject still does. At least according to MSDN.

Comment: @DickKusleika I don't see a ListObject object belonging to a worksheet. They may have disposed of it.

Comment: You access a ListObject via the ListObjects.Item method or the Range.ListObject method. To get the ListObject instance named Table1, you use `Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Item("Table1")`. Now the variable 'lo' will refer to a single instance of a ListObject (the one named Table1 and returned by the Item method). You can access all of the properties and methods through the lo variable.

Comment: @DickKusleika Okay that makes sense. Appreciate it. Wish they would have kept it consistent where all QueryTables, whether created programmatically or by the UI, where children of a worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
Range("ClassifiedAsSupply").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
```

Thanks to Dingbatdata: https://www.dingbatdata.com/2017/11/24/referencing-listobjects-with-vba/#comment-719