# How to remove QueryTable connections not used in this workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I only have this one workbook opened (no other worbooks were opened at the time), and noticed a bunch of Data connections listed. Upon further investigation, it shows that these connections are not "used in this workbook" (again, the weird thing is that I only have this workbook open, so if connections are not used here, where else are they used in?)

[image: Screenshot from Excel 2010]

Using the following code, it shows that the QueryTables.Count is all 0s in all worksheets in this workbook. So is there a way to programmatically (VBA, not C#), to remove the connections? Really would hate to individually and manually remove connections

```
Dim Worksheet As Object
For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Debug.Print (Worksheet.QueryTables.Count)
Next
```

Comment: Tevlyn's answer is good. You should note that, if you're using Excel 2007 or higher, your test above is faulty. That's because in those versions `QueryTables` most likely reside in a `ListObject`, like Worksheet.ListObject.QueryTable. Of course a table (ListObject) doesn't necessarily contain a QueryTable - if you're interested, I wrote a post about testing for them: http://yoursumbuddy.com/four-listobject-querytable-tests-better-last/. Dick Kusleika also wrote a definitive SO answer on the topic:http://stackoverflow.com/a/18069060/293078

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
Sub deleteConnections()
Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    conn.Delete
Next conn
End Sub
```

That removed a bunch of connections that were actually active in my workbook. Should also do the trick for connections that are not used.

Comment: Thanks! I was googling around, and figured out the solution independently (except I used Thisworkbook, not Activeworkbook). Good stuff. thanks. Marked yours as chosen solution.