# Refresh All Queries in Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

This works for .xls books, but can it be altered for .xlsx workbooks as well?  Or is their syntax that will work for both?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub RefreshQueries()
  Dim wks As Worksheet
  Dim qt As QueryTable
  For Each wks In Worksheets
    For Each qt In wks.QueryTables
        qt.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Next qt
  Next wks
  Set qt = Nothing
  Set wks = Nothing
End Sub
```

EDIT --
So it seems my syntax does refresh .xlsx workbooks, but not queries that are from sql server.  How can those be refreshed via VBA.

Comment: So I checked whether the queries in my test workbook were actually being refreshed, and they weren't - see edit to my answer. Thanks for bringing this quirk to my attention! Now I have to go and check a bunch of my own spreadsheets to see if I need to deal with this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, no macro will work in a `.xlsx` workbook because .xlsx workbooks can't contain macros - you need to save as a **macro-enabled workbook** which has the extension `.xlsm`.

In Excel 2007 and later, user created external data connections to SQL Server data sources (amongst others) will result not in a QueryTables member, but in a ListObject which will possess a QueryTable object that can be accessed via the `ListObject.QueryTable` property - see Dick Kusleika's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18069060/24447) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067070/excel-vba-refer-to-querytable-objects-by-name). The following code should refresh both types of queries:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub RefreshQueries()

  Dim wks As Worksheet
  Dim qt As QueryTable
  Dim lo As ListObject

  For Each wks In Worksheets
    For Each qt In wks.QueryTables
        qt.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Next qt

    For Each lo In wks.ListObjects
        lo.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Next lo

  Next wks

  Set qt = Nothing
  Set wks = Nothing
End Sub
```

I wasn't previously familiar with the `ListObject` type so I don't know if you can have a `ListObject` on a worksheet that doesn't have a `QueryTable`, which might cause an error in the above code - you might need to check for this.

Comment: Is it possible to iterate the worksheets refreshing all, as opposed to specifying a sheet name like the example shows?

Comment: Be careful. The above assumes all your ListObjects are "Query" types. If they are "Pivot" types, you could crash Excel forcing it to think it's a QueryTable object when it's a PivotTable object. I suggest a test for XlListObjectSourceType value '3' be done to be sure. Just a thought.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from @nekomatic throws error 1004 for me (although it apparently works for others).  I use this instead:

```
Public Sub RefreshAllQueries()
    ' Refresh all queries (tables querying data from another source).

    Dim iWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim iTable As Excel.ListObject
    Dim iQueryTable As Excel.QueryTable

    ' Check each worksheet.
    For Each iWorksheet In Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        ' Check each table.
        For Each iTable In iWorksheet.ListObjects

            If iTable.SourceType = Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcQuery Then
                ' Table is a query table.
                With iTable.QueryTable
                    .BackgroundQuery = False    ' setting to wait for query to refresh
                    .Refresh
                End With

            End If

        Next iTable


        For Each iQueryTable In iWorksheet.QueryTables
            iQueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False  ' wait for query to refresh
        Next iQueryTable

    Next iWorksheet
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the better and correct answer, as it checks the object type

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`

Objects that have the `BackgroundQuery` property set to `True` are refreshed in the background