# Refresh excel query table with vbs script

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I would like to refresh excel query table with a vbs script but i didn't find any guide on web.
I have one query table (connection name = "VISIONI23" in the sheet "VISIONI") to refresh.
I've done a different kind of attemps but noone didn't work.
Feel free to correct all the code.

My last attempt (that shows a different kind of run time error) is this:

```vb
Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
objExcelApp.Visible = True
objExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False


sFilePathXlsm = "G:\Groups\Management Equipment\CONTROLLO_VISIONI1.xlsm"
Set iWb = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(sFilePathXlsm)
Set iWs = iWb.Sheets("VISIONI").Connections("Query - VISIONI23")

iWs.Refresh

iWb.Save
iWb.Close
objExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True
objExcelApp.Quit
```

Comment: Set the query table to refresh in opening and forget about it?

Comment: I would like to refresh table query with a closed excel file. Can I do this operation with vbs script?

Comment: Yes, by refreshing the table itself, rather than its connection?

Comment: I tried to refresh all the workbook and it seems work well (I don't receive any kind of run time error) but when I open the file, table isn't uploaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Refresh All Queries in Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31476040/1422451)