# How to name the connection used by a QueryTable

Tags: excel, vba

My current code:

```
ConnectionName = "testCon"
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://test/test?values=[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]~[]&format=csv" _
    , Destination:=Range("$D$1"))
    .Name = ConnectionName
End With
```

This results in a new connection being created, named "Connection", and if the process is repeated "Connection1" is created, then "Connection2" and so on. Is there any way to name the connection?

the `.Name` parameter seems to refer to the data range name, rather than connection name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18067070/1161309

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I didn't find a way to directly name a new querytable connection, so I had to code a macro that looks for the new name in the connection list, and then renames it.

```
Sub NewQueryTable(ConnectionName As String)
    OriginalConnections = ConnectionList()

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://myconnection&format=csv" _
        , Destination:=Range("$D$1"))
        .Name = ConnectionName
    End With


' Looking for the newly created Connection to rename it
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    UpdatedConnections = ConnectionList()
    Dim NewConnectionName As String
    Dim CheckedString As String


    For Each conn In UpdatedConnections
        CheckedString = conn
        If Not (IsInArray(CheckedString, OriginalConnections)) Then
            NewConnectionName = CheckedString
        End If
    Next conn

    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(NewConnectionName)
            .Name = ConnectionName
            .Description = ""
    End With


End Sub


Function ConnectionList() As Variant

    Dim NumOfConnections As Integer
    Dim Counter As Integer


    NumOfConnections = 0
    Counter = 1


    Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
    For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        NumOfConnections = NumOfConnections + 1
    Next conn


    Dim ConnectionNames() As String, size As Integer, i As Integer
    size = NumOfConnections
    ReDim ConnectionNames(size)

    For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        ConnectionNames(Counter) = conn.Name
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Next conn

    ConnectionList = ConnectionNames


End Function

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean

        IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

This still comes up as a top result in Google, so I thought I'd answer. You use the `WorkbookConnection` property of the `QueryTable` object:

```
Dim oQT As QueryTable

Set oQT = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).QueryTable

'Rename the connection
With oQT.WorkbookConnection
    .Name = "NewConnectionName"
    .Description = "New Connection Description"
End With

'Delete the connection
oQT.WorkbookConnection.Delete
```

Comment: This is a much better solution. Using built-in features instead of creating new ones.